# How to add 1 UTC day to javascript date?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc, iso

Using javascript, how can I take a non-UTC date, add 1 UTC day, zero out time time(s), and then convert it to a ISO string?

---

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

> 2017-10-10T16:00:49.915Z

---

**Desired UTC Datestring**

> 2017-10-11T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: So… you have added 7h59m10s085? Do you mean rounding up to the next day?

Comment: This can help with the second part of your problem `setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I get the date in milliseconds, add 1 whole day in milliseconds.
I then divide by a day in milliseconds,  truncate, and then multiple again by a day in milliseconds.

```js
var d = new Date('2017-10-10T16:00:49.915Z');

function nextDayUTC(d) {
  var aDay = 1440 * 60 * 1000;
  var d2 = new Date( Math.trunc((d.getTime() + aDay)/aDay)*aDay);
  return d2;
}

function nextDayLocal(d) {
  //basically set to start of the day
  //add 36 hrs, this pretty much ensures next day
  //add then reset the hours back to 0
  var hr36 = 36 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var d2 = new Date(d);
  d2.setHours(0,0,0,0); 
  d2.setTime(d2.getTime() + hr36);
  d2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return d2;
}

console.log(d)
console.log("Next Day UTC");
console.log(nextDayUTC(d).toISOString());
console.log("Next Day Local");
console.log(nextDayLocal(d).toString());
```

Comment: Does this correctly handle the case where this is the last day before Daylight Savings Time starts or ends?

Comment: Yes, as everything I'm doing would be based on UTC.  Daylight savings is more of a render thing,.  UTC time is constant.

Comment: Ah, yes! Sorry, I somehow overlooked that it was rendering to ISO format instead of locale-specific. :)

Comment: I've updated to do next day using local time,.. Oops, bit of a bug updated again.. :)

Comment: Adding a UTC day is much simpler as `d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1)`. Also, there's no need to create the second date in `nextDayLocal` or even to calculate the milliseconds in 36 hours, you can do `d2.setUTCHours(d2.getUTCHours() + 36)` or even `var d2 = new Date(+d + hr36)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG  I personally like working in milliseconds, I usually have constants setup for things like days / hours / mins etc, and the spec for out of range inputs for setUTCDate & setUTCHours  `attempts to update the date` sounds naive.  The extra date in the nextDayLocal, yeah that could be dropped, I'll update..

Comment: @RobG Also `d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1)` is not doing the same thing. You would still need to clear out the Time part, say using  `setHours` again.

Comment: @Keith—there is still `d2.setHours(0,0,0,0);`.